# Remove the last element's specific text

Tags: javascript

For example i have a for loop which will generate some kind of words

```
for(var i=0;i<profile.test.length;i++){
    var wordList = wordList  + profile.test[i].text.map(function(k) {
        return k.split(/,\s*/).join('+');
    }).join(' , ') + '|';
};
```

and this will return something like

```
hhh1+hhhh2|fdsg+gsdg , 123+1232|
```

but i want to remove the last "|"

```
hhh1+hhhh2|fdsg+gsdg , 123+1232
```

how could i do that?

Comment: You want to remove last character, or last specific text string?

Comment: What is the value of `profile`?

Comment: it's a random number depends on the JSON

Comment: @anson920520— *profile* can't be a number, please see [*How to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the substr method of the generated String to remove the last character:

```
wordList = wordList.substr(0, wordList.length -1);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have the outer loop return an array you can use `join` on it.

This works because [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) takes the elements of an array and "joins" them together into a single string using the passed in argument as the delimiter/separator.

This means that `var example = ['a', 'b', 'c'].join('|')` sets `example` to `'a|b|c'`.

---

Without knowing the value of `profile` in your example it's hard to refactor your code an know that it works. But, if you modify your existing code you should be able to do something along the lines of this:

```
profile.test.map(function(item) {
  return item.map(function(k) {
    return k.split(/,\s*/).join('+');
  }).join(' , ')
}.join('|');
```

---

Here's another example of a similar problem that works using the same concept as mentioned above:

```js
// hhh1 , hhhh2|fdsg , gsdg
  
var items = [{text:'hhh1, hhhh2'}, {text: 'fdsg, gsdg'}]

var out = items.map(function(item) {
  return item.text.split(/,\s*/).join(' , ');
}).join('|');

console.log(out)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change '|' to

```
i !== profile.test.length - 1 ? '|' : ''
```

which would change your code to:

```
for(var i=0;i<profile.test.length;i++){
    var wordList = wordList  + profile.test[i].text.map(function(k) {
        return k.split(/,\s*/).join('+');
    }).join(' , ') + (i !== (profile.test.length - 1) ? '|' : '');
};
```

Answer (score 0):

A general solution when the last "|" isnt the last character would be by define its position could be like this:

```
str ="abc|def|ghi|nope";
var lastPos = str.lastIndexOf('|');
var wordStart = str.substring(0,lastPos);
var wordEnd = str.substring(lastPos+1);
alert(wordStart + wordEnd);
```

JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/e59erp0h/

In real word szenarios, id recomment to shorten it (unless you want to play arond with ANYTHING ;)(

Answer (score -1):

Add this code after your loop to remove the last character

```
wordList = wordList.substring(0, wordList.length - 2);
```